# Pygame is not installing in macOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pygame, sdl-2

While installing PYGAME on MACBOOK, the following error has been occurring even though i have Xcode on MAC. I tried to install pygame using pip command.

Python version is 3.7.3
Both pip and python are in same folder

The command used for installing is : pip install pygame

Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame ... error

```
ERROR: Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tg/vsvw2pys51n86kyv6s46cx4c0000gr/T/pip-install-clye7bq4/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/tg/vsvw2pys51n86kyv6s46cx4c0000gr/T/pip-record-978dvy0k/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
ERROR: running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/threads
copying src_py/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/threads
copying src_py/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/threads
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/constants_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/fastevent_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/overlay_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/touch_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/touch_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
copying test/version_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/test_utils
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/docs
copying docs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/docs
copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/docs
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/audiocapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/textinput.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
copying examples/video.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pygame/examples
running build_ext
building 'pygame.gfxdraw' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src_c
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src_c/SDL_gfx

gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src_c/gfxdraw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src_c/gfxdraw.o
In file included from src_c/gfxdraw.c:33:
In file included from src_c/pygame.h:32:
src_c/_pygame.h:216:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
---
For help with compilation see:
    https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
To contribute to pygame development see:
    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
---
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
```

> ERROR: Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/tg/vsvw2pys51n86kyv6s46cx4c0000gr/T/pip-install-clye7bq4/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/tg/vsvw2pys51n86kyv6s46cx4c0000gr/T/pip-record-978dvy0k/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/tg/vsvw2pys51n86kyv6s46cx4c0000gr/T/pip-install-clye7bq4/pygame/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame installation issue in mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974339/pygame-installation-issue-in-mac-os)

Answer (score 1):

This error means you are missing a shared library. In this case it is [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/).

If you look at the [Mac install instructions on the pygame wiki](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/macintosh), you will see that it expects you to install some other libraries needed for pygame to install and run properly.

It expects you to use homebrew to install some SDL libs and a package called `hg`, which is [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

If you have homebrew installed you can simply run:

```
brew install hg sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi
```

Then re-install pygame as before.