# Cannot open include file: 'SDL.h'

Tags: python, pygame, sdl

I'm desperate for any help that anyone can provide.  I'm trying to install pygame 1.9.1 with 64 bit python 2.7 on a windows 64 bit machine.  I have Visual Studio C++ Express 2008 and Visual Studio 2013, but the installation attempts to use the Express edition.  This is the error message I keep getting: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDL.h': No such file or directory."

I've downloaded the SDL library from libsdl.org

I've followed the tutorial from here: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet0508e/index.php
(the program I wrote worked, but the pygame one still won't)

I've followed a video similar to the lazyfoo tutorial that told me to add additional libraries.

I tried to follow this response: [Pygame cannot find include file "sdl.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841654/pygame-cannot-find-include-file-sdl-h) 
(my setup.py doesn't have that line)

I've looked up the error message on microsoft's website, and I can't figure out how to fix it.  I can't even find where the include statement is within the pygame files.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try [PyGame binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) - and you will have no need to compile it on your own.

Comment: `Unofficial Windows Binaries` is good place for Windows users :) If it works then you can mark my answer as accepted (and eventually upvote) :)